# How to modify the source file path of a BigQuery external table in Airflow?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, data-warehouse, external-tables

There is a process which exports some CSV files to GCS and puts the current datetime into the path, e.g.:

```
gs://my_gcs_bucket/path/to/export/<current_timestamp>/exported_file_1.csv
gs://my_gcs_bucket/path/to/export/<current_timestamp>/exported_file_2.csv
```

I want to create an external table for these files before I cast its columns and merge with other tables.

The problem is that I can't implement a DAG in Airflow which can handle the changing timestamps.

---

I can create an external table by specifying the path (with the current timestamp), but for tomorrow's exports this external table will not read the new files. But I will need tomorrow the same `project_name.dataset.tablename` for processing.

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator

CreateExternalBqTable = BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator(
    task_id                             = "CreateExternalBqTable",
    field_delimiter                     = '|',
    destination_project_dataset_table   = f'{project_name}.{dataset}.{tablename}',
    bucket                              = BUCKET_URI,
    source_objects                      = [ 'path/to/export/2021-12-12-12-12-12/exported_file_*' ],
    schema_fields                       = generate_custom_struct()
)
```

If tomorrow I'll try to run the same table creation task again it will fail because the external table already exists.
I can delete the existing external table then recreate it again to ensure it does not fail the external table creation task, but if it's already deleted then this will fail:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryDeleteTableOperator

DeleteExternalBqTable = BigQueryDeleteTableOperator(
    task_id                 = "DeleteExternalBqTable",
    deletion_dataset_table  = f'{project_name}.{dataset}.{tablename}',
)
```

---

What is the good pattern here?
Should I **always delete and recreate the external table** just because of the new timestamps?
It seems to me very bad and error prone pattern.

Or could I **change the path under an existing external table** somehow?

I would be much happier if I could **separate the initialization and deletion phases of my external table** from the daily runs and not always delete or create them. I plan to **initialize these tables only once** and move away the CSV files if I'm done with the processing and keep the external tables empty until the next run.

(I need a working solution for Airflow 1.x)

Answer (score 2):

In `BigQueryDeleteTableOperator`  you can use `ignore_if_missing` argument as documented in [Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery.BigQueryDeleteTableOperator).

But if you don't want to recreate the table every time consider using idempotent operator  `BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator` to create the table (it will skip creation if table already exists) and then `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` to load the data. In this way you will separate the creation and load